# ASP.Net MVC Login Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with asp.net mvc application on hosting .

when I use login page on local machine it worked without problem but if I upload website on hosting ( Plesk Windows ) and I called Login method,

show Error :

> An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.

InnerException :

```
    Access to the path `C:/Windows/system32/configsystemprofile/AppData/Local/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys` is denied.
```

Source File :

```
    //File Header
    private readonly UserManager<Mak_Users> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<Mak_Users> _signInManager;

    //Login Method
    var qUser = db.Users.Where(a => a.UserName == model.Usr_NatCode).SingleOrDefault();
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(qUser, model.RememberMe);
```

Please help me for fix this problem :((

Comment: What's in the `innerException`?

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' is denied.

Comment: Try changing the Application Pool identity on IIS Server from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "LocalSystem" - source: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1983

Comment: I changed the Application Pool identity on IIS Server from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "LocalSystem"
but My problem not fixed .